# How can I fix this screen > php > No screen session found

Tags: php

I send screen command for php but

for example

```
<?php
system("screen -S screen444 -X -p0 eval 'stuff \"restart\"^m'")
?>
```

I send this command

Error: No screen session found.

But screen is running

with any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Apart from the fact that I have no clue what you're talking about it seems to me that this is rather a sysadmin question?

Comment: Are you calling this PHP script from a browser or from command line?  If it's from a browser, my guess is the PHP user (the user your webserver is running as) is different from the user who started the screen.

Comment: Yes calling browser but
Server belongs to me
works only one screen

If I login ssh and run this command

  |||  screen -S screen444 -X -p0 eval 'stuff "restart"^m'
|||
success working.

but when executing browser

Not working ( No screen session found )

Comment: @user1288273: Are you logging to to the server as the same user that's running the webserver?  Usually apache runs as its own user, so it won't be able to access screens of other users.

Comment: I did not think this ever.
how can I set this permission?
My php files ??

Comment: I don't think you can fix that using files permissions, you would rather need to impersonate the correct user. I think `sudo -u` does something along that if you have sudo access.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Doesn't make sense.

[root@tau matlink]# screen -ls
There are screens on:
 4916.matservo (Attached)
 4913.matservi (Attached)
2 Sockets in /run/screens/S-root.

In browser:
Message from server: No screen session found. 
matserv is not running
USER is root

Answer (score 0):

This won't help if you're *nix, but if Apache is running as a service on Windows, you can change the login by running `services.msc`.  In the properties, on the Log On tab, change the Log on as: to "This account" and fill in the rest as needed.

I did this so that PHP could use the sessions I started. However I am only able to `screen -ls` to see the sessions. I cannot `-X stuff` them for some reason, no error and no output. my similar question: [cygwin screen session problems through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882438/cygwin-screen-session-problems-through-php)

Comment: i figured out how to stuff.. see my question for details

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have run into the same problem.

When I run `screen -ls` from bash in the shell, it looks in `/run/screens/S-root`.

When I run `screen -ls` from bash in PHP, it looks in `/run/screens/S-http`.

`$USER` is `root` in both cases - but perhaps PHP simply doesn't update the environment variable when it adds its own sandboxing.

If you set `multiuser on` and `acladd http` in your `.screenrc`, `screen -ls` will still fail, since it doesn't have permission to look in `/run/screens/S-root`.

Instead, you should set `multiuser on` and `acladd root`, and start the screen as a process belonging to `http`. My start line, for example, is:

`su - $username -c "screen -A -m -d -h 100 -c /tau/sys/commands/-config/matservirc -S matservi ssh matserv@$2"`

where `$username` is `http` and `$2` is an IP address.

You can send a command to it like this:

`su - $username -c "screen -S matservi -p 0 -X stuff \"cat > ~/server/matlink/access/matinput`(linebreak)`\""`

and attach it to `root` (or whatever other account you're using) like this:

`screen -r http/matservi`