# cygwin screen session problems through php

Tags: php, cygwin, gnu-screen

Windows, cygwin.
I've successfully created a screen session and used it how i would like from a command prompt:
`screen -S remote` then can stuff it like so: `screen -S remote -X stuff blah` and everthing works just peachy. However, I am trying to do the stuffing from a PHP script. `<?php exec("screen -S remote -X stuff blah"); ?>` to no avail.

It seems that PHP can only use screen with certain options. `<?php exec("screen -ls"); ?>` works as expected, listing the current screen sessions, but i cannot stuff anything into a session :(

I am even able to create a session through PHP, but am never able to "use" the session. I've even tried `screen -S remote -p 0 stuff blah`

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: exec() doesn't give you an interactive terminal shell. How do you expect screen and whatever you're running inside of it draw their interfaces if there's nothing to draw an interface on?

Comment: i was expecting that, if there was already a screen session running with something running in it, you could `exec(screen -S remote -X stuff ...)` and it would send it to that screen session. i can achieve expected results using a separate command prompt, i assumed that the exec() would behave this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a bit of experimenting, i managed to successful stuff.

`exec("start screen -S remote -X stuff blah");`